# Javascript returning the Objects from searching result in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, filter

I want to find if any property has the value of my query. Let's say the query is 'Tip' and then it would return any object that contain those strings in the property.

```
[
  {
  "category": "Kelas 10",
  "created": "2018-12-06 17:26:16",
  "image": "cover.jpg",
  "lessons": "1",
   "name": "Randi Eka Setiawan",
  "rate_count": "8",
   "title": "Bimbel Kimia",
  },
  {
    "category": "Kelas Skill",
    "title": "Tips & Trick Play Guitar",
   },
]
```

in this case the 2nd object has contains those strings in property of title from "Tips & Trick Play Guitar". and it should only return the second array... or any objects with those of strings so I will have the array with correct objects that matched

I'mnot quite sure how to search properly:

```
 data.filter(item => { 
 // first iterate the array ?

      Object.keys(item).map(i => {
      // then iterate the objects ?

        if(item[i] === query) {
        // compare property value contain my query ?

           return item

           //EDIT: and then return the objects that match ? shouldn't it be like that?
       }
   })
})
```

Comment: "return any array that", "the 2nd array" - an object is not an array.

Comment: 1. Comments start with `//` 2. `filter()` returns the new array so you need `data = data.filter(...);` 3. the function passed to filter is supposed to return truthy / falsey, not the item. 4. you don't want to use `===` but a suitable String function, searching for "js string contains string" should give plenty of useful results

Comment: Do you wish to only filter on the `title` property in each object? Should filtering ignore casing?

Comment: In general, start with a simple version, get it to work as intended, then expand. And use `console.log()` to check everything.

Comment: @ASDFGerte i meant, the 2nd obj in array, @Philip no i want to filter any property that has the strings, whether it's `title` or `category`, @Chris G yeah I did with a lot of console log, at some point i got the object result that matched but i have no idea to return the obj that contain any of those

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Object.prototype.values()`/`Object.prototype.some()`. This example uses a case-insensitive string search, you'd probably have to adapt it for your needs and perform proper escaping if needed.

```js
var objectsIn = [
  {
  "category": "Kelas 10",
  "created": "2018-12-06 17:26:16",
  "image": "cover.jpg",
  "lessons": "1",
   "name": "Randi Eka Setiawan",
  "rate_count": "8",
   "title": "Bimbel Kimia",
  },
  {
    "category": "Kelas Skill",
    "title": "Tips & Trick Play Guitar",
   },
]

function filterObjects(objArray, filterText) {
  return objArray.filter((obj) => {
    return Object.values(obj).some(value => {
      return new RegExp(filterText, 'i').test(value);
    });
  });
}

console.log(filterObjects(objectsIn, 'Tip'));
```

Comment: Without proper escaping `new RegExp(filterText, 'i')` will eventually blow up in your face. Imo. better: `return typeof value === "string" && filterText.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase();`

Comment: However, this would only match the complete string, so it would be even better to go the `indexOf() !== -1` route then.